# Attempt to dereference a null object

Tags: soql

working on below class where I am writing a soql query outside the main loop but getgin error: "Attempt to dereference a null object". I am assuming it because of writing query for amap outside main loop. Can someone suggest correction to my class.

```
public class casetrgtest1 {

    public class caseVars {
        public Id caseId;
        public Id accountId;
        public Id parentAccountId;
        public map<Id, map<Id, string>> assetMap;
    }

    public static void postCases(list<id> caseIds){
        list<caseVars> caseVars = new list<caseVars>();
        list<Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, accountId, account.parentId, contactId, contact.otherphone 
                               FROM case WHERE Id IN :caseIds];
        Map<Id, caseVars> caseMap = new Map<Id, caseVars>();
        list<Id> accountIdList = new list<Id>();
        map<id, string> amap = new map<id, string>();

        for(case c: caseList){
            caseVars caseVar = new caseVars();
            caseVar.caseId = c.Id;
            caseVar.accountId = c.accountId;

            if(c.account.parentId != null){
                accountIdList.add(c.account.parentId);
                caseVar.assetMap.put(c.account.parentId,aMap);
            }
            caseMap.put(c.Id, caseVar);
        }

    for (Asset asset : [SELECT Id, Name, description, AccountId FROM Asset WHERE AccountId IN :accountIdList]) {
        aMap.put(asset.id,asset.Description);
    }

    String jsonString = JSON.serialize(caseMap.values());
    system.debug(jsonString);  
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Which line are you getting the error at?

Comment: It looks like `caseIds` is the only collection which could be `null`, and you never check against that.

Comment: getting error at `caseVar.assetMap.put(c.account.parentId,aMap);`

Comment: Adrian, I am checking size of caseIds in my trigger and only if size > 1,  trigger calls this class

Comment: @pmvsdt - as a best practice you should not rely on calling classes to check that the data is correct before sending. Always check in the method.class executing/evaluating the data to ensure it continues to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You instantiate the class but never the inner map...

here

```
caseVar.assetMap.put(c.account.parentId,aMap)
```

An easy way to handle this is to update the class definition as such:

```
public class caseVars {
        public Id caseId;
        public Id accountId;
        public Id parentAccountId;
        public map<Id, map<Id, string>> assetMap = New Map<Id, Map<Id,String>>();
    }
```

or

```
public class caseVars {
        public Id caseId;
        public Id accountId;
        public Id parentAccountId;
        public map<Id, map<Id, string>> assetMap;

        public caseVars(){

            assetMap = new Map<Id, Map<Id,String>>();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. This perfectly worked and also as per your suggestion, will update my trigger

Comment: Putting it in the constructor seems a lot nicer. I would probably also make it `final` so you know it will **never** be `null`.